# I keep getting a shrunk plot when I try to do a plot in R using data from a file I downloaded

Tags: r

[image: This is a graph of expenses(y variable) against income (x variable)]

The graph is smashed into about 10% of the total area available.
I have not encountered this before.
What is going on?
How do I produce a reasonably sized graph?

Answer (score 4):

```
# This is a plot
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
x<-1:10; y=x*x
plot(x, y, type="b")

# Here is how the plot shrinks
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
x<-1:10; y=x*x
plot(x, y, type="b")

# With dev.off() you clean the settings and the graph should be big again
x<-1:10; y=x*x
plot(x, y, type="b")
```

[image]

**vs.**

[image]

Comment: Almost certainly. The plot from OP is sized for 3 rows x 2 columns exactly. `mfrow` or `mfcol` or `layout` is active.